# Вопросы про сети и маршрутизацию wan пакетов. Спуффинг IP. UDP

Tags: сеть, ip, udp

Никак не могу достучаться ни до одной машины обычных юзеров.

Просил их отключать фаерволлы, все что есть.

Ни одна машина не ответила нa пинг, на udp пакет не ответила "Destination is unreachable".

Смотрел всё в wireshark. Пакеты слал и через питон, и через netcat.

Короче 0 реакции. Однако когда меня пингуют моя машина отвечает по-полной.

А теперь вопросы:

Как работают мобильные сети, и чем практически отличается связь с юзером на модеме и кабельным? Такой же вопрос про пользователей wifi сетей, чьих роутер в конечном итоге подключен к кабелю.
Что не дает пакетам дойти до целевой машины, кроме как фаерволл?

Работает ли в 2019 ip спуффинг? Если я укажу в заголовке udp пакета `Source` чужой ip, доживет ли пакет? В моем случае пакет просто не шел, когда я указывал ip сети друга.

Если найдется человек, который поможет разобраться и постучать его машину с включенным wireshark, то я буду очень счастлив

UDP: Все по прежнему так, машины 0 реакции, ОДНАКО. 
Если пингануть и подождать минуту, почему то начинают приходить ответы после сотни пингов ( на новые пинги, а не на 100 старых ).

Вообще бред, учитывая, что на все остальное машина не отвечает

Comment: Как обстоят дела у вас и у ваших юзеров с NAT-ом?

Comment: Спасибо за направление. Почитал про NAT. Кажется именно в нем и дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует так называемая модель OSI, которая описывает модель сетевого взаимодействия. Рекомендую ознакомиться с описанием данного термина.

С точки зрения этой модели, вас не должно волновать каким физическим методом удаленный клиент выходит на связь. Мобильные сети, кабельное подключение или wifi - это все физическая среда передачи данных. Даже если клиентский компьютер подключён к интернету кабелем это ещё не значит, что один из узлов, не будет подключен через радиорелейное устройство передачи данных в какой нибудь деревне и т.п.

В роутерах помимо Firewall'а так же присутствует NAT который управляет маршрутизацией пакетов и определяет какому из  локальных пользователей он предназначен. Подключен ли удаленный пользователь к роутеру по wifi или по кабелю вас не должно волновать и вообще как то затрагивать.   Это всего лишь физический уровень передачи данных. Вы же оперируете более высокими уровнями.

По мимо Firewall'ов на компьютере они есть и в роутерах. Так же в роутерах есть NAT, который отвечает за маршрутизацию пакетов. Различные настройки проброса портов и прочее... Так же в некоторых роутерах есть опциональная функция позволяющая не отвечать на запросы из вне. И на некоторых она включена по умолчанию.

В случае смобильными сетями немного сложнее. В некоторых случаях операторы могут использовать серые ip. Если вкратце - это работает как NAT в роутерах. Сильно утрируя: мобильный оператор - роутер, а телефоны, модемы и прочее - клиенты подключенные к этому роутеру.

Comment: как мне известно,  в рамках "физической среды передачи данных" могут отбрасываться пакеты и фильтроваться. Поэтому я придал этой теме такой акцент. Спасибо, ответ хороший, ещё бы узнать что со спуфингом ip, потому что я даже и не знаю как проверить на практике.

Comment: Пакеты не фильтруются на физическом уровне. Они могут фильтроваться на L2 и L3. На физическом уровне могут быть только потери пакетов. Если данные передаются с использованием TCP - эти потери будут компенсироваться особенностями протокола. В случае UDP данные могут не доходить. Единственное, что гарантирует UDP - пакет данных дойдет полностью или не дойдет до адресата вовсе. Хотя в наше время это не так критично т.к. UDP большинстве случаев используется для передачи потоковых данных (звук, видео, изображение и т.п.) потери которых не критичны.

Comment: Так же следует учитывать, что UDP - протокол без установления связи. При передачи данных на той стороне получателя может и не существовать